# Determine current roomba state / operating mode

Tags: roomba

Using the [SCI messages](http://www.robotappstore.com/files/KB/Roomba/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf), I would like to determine the current operating mode or state of a iRobot Roomba 780. Finally, I would like to detect and separate four states:

- Cleaning
- In docking station
- Returning to docking station
- Error (e.g. trapped on obstacle)

What is a fast and reliable way to detect those states using [SCI data](http://www.robotappstore.com/files/KB/Roomba/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf)?

The Roomba SCI Sensor packets "Remote Control Command" and "Buttons" seem to return the currently called commands and not the currently executed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial answers to my question:
The "current" sensor message indicates if the roomba is operating (< 0) or in the docking station (> 0).
Open remains error handling and "searching for docking station".
I'll adapt my answers if I get further.

EDIT 2015-05-05:
The solution which seems to work looks in pseudo code as follows:

```
if ( charging_state == 5 ) {
  return ERROR;
}
else if ( charging_state == 2 ) {
  return CHARGING;
}
else {
  if ( charger_available == 2 ) {
    return INDOCK;
  }
  else {
    if ( main_brush_current != 0 && current < 0 ) {
      return WORKING;
    }
    else {
      return ERROR;
    }
  }
}
```

The "variables" within the if statements are corresponding sensor messages given in the document, linked by @Andrea.

The "return values" indicate the corresponding Roomba states.

Comment: Roomba doesn't *always* draw current while sitting on the dock. It stops charging to allow the battery to cool off.

Answer (score 2):

The manual you linked to is not for the Roomba 780. You'll want to reference the one on this page: http://www.irobot.com/create

You can tell if the robot is on the dock by checking the "Home Base" bit in the charging sources available packet (#34).

There is currently no way to know via the OI if Roomba is trying to find the dock.

Comment: Quite a good hint, thanks. I try to find correlations between different sensor States in order to determine the overall Roomba state, incl. "error".